# Simple Chess Board with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Unfortunately I can't get the images of chess pieces to fill the chessboard I have made.  The chessboard looks nice, but I have created code I have inserted to create a bishop.  I've tried to add the bishop ontop of the square on the 2nd column every other one.  Unfortunately I get a very small bishop in the center of each tile! Here is my styling, `.td1` = white square, `.td2` = black square on a regular chess board.

```
image 
{
    position : relative;
    max-width : 100%;
    max-height : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

table 
{
    border-collapse : collapse;
}

.td1 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin : 0px;
    background-color : gray;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color : black; 
     position : relative; 
     width : 12px;
     height : 12px;
}


.td2
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin : 0px;
    background-color : yellow;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color : black;
     position : relative;
     width : 12px;
     height : 12px; 
}
```

Here is the javascript code, I have added an extra if statement that will be changed later on, to insert a bishop image every other one on 2nd column.

```
    for (x=0; x<rows; x++)
    {
        board +="<tr>";
        for (y=0; y<cols;y++)
        {
        switch1 = x%2;
        if (y==1 && y%2 == switch1) //just for test purposes
            board +="<td class=\"" + "td1\">"   + "<img src=\"white bishop.png\" width=12px height=12px>" /<---add image here.
        else if (y%2 == switch1)
          board +="<td class=\"" + "td1\">" ; 
        else 
          board +="<td class=\"" + "td2\">";
        }
        board +="</tr>";
    }

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="sample.js" src="model.js"></script>
<script src="model.js"></script>
</head>


<body onload ="start()">
 <table>
<div id ="gridDiv"> </div>
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a live example ?

Comment: @Shomz Feel free to do it, but note there is some external ressources, so I'm pretty sure we won't be able to reproduce it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you put your code in a codepen. Just as a glance, in the css you have image{} (very first line), where it probably should be img.

Comment: @enguerranws, you were right. Some crucial components are missing. Sorry if I sounded too harsh there.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Attributes `width` or `height` for an `<img>` element take the value in pixels, e.g. `width=100`. There are no other allowed values like `%` or `em`, so you don't need and actually must not add `px` to your values.

Change `board +="<td class=\"" + "td1\">"   + "<img src=\"white bishop.png\" width=12px height=12px>"` to `board +="<td class=\"" + "td1\">"   + "<img src=\"white bishop.png\" width=12 height=12>"` and give it a try.